# Deploy from build history

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I have configured a multi-branch pipeline for my **Bitbucket** repository. My configuration is the staging branch gets automatically triggered and deploy to staging environment.

Now I want to implement a use case where I should be able to select one build from **‘Build history’** and deploy that build to production. Can any one give a suggestion on how to solve it?

Comment: Did you find a way to do this? If yes please share